# Multiple documents & signers, document order incorrect in embedded signing

Tags: docusignapi, document, signing

I have an an envelope with multiple documents and signers.

All signers have shared, locked textTabs for the first document (documentId "1", the first one in the array of documents), but no sign here, date signed, or full name tabs.

Also, all signers have non-shared, locked textTabs, and a sign here, a date signed, and a full name tab for exactly 1 other document (a signature page).

I've enabled enforceSignerVisibilty.

Everything work as expected with the exception that within the embedded signing UI, the signer is immediately shown the document that requires signing, skipping the 1st document.  However, the first document is included first during the final review step, and is also included first when downloading the combined document for that signer.

How can I get the 1st document presented 1st in the embedded signing UI?  I've already tried making it a supplemental document with modal display and 'view_read_accept' for signerMustAcknowledge.  The UI and flow works well, but the text tabs are not filled in.

*** Update ***
I spend many hours trying different combinations of settings and documents and found that there are unexpected undocumented oddities in the the docusign API that caused this behavior:

1 - The first document was a PDF document, but the other documents were HTML. We had to use PDF for all of the documents.  Using PDF converted to HTML by setting htmlDefinition = { source: 'document' } for the first document and HTML for the others did not work.  So now we're generating PDFs for the signature pages instead of simply coding HTML.

2 - We use anchorText which causes the tab's documentId to be ignored!  So we had to use different anchorText values for different documents, even though they logically represent the same thing!.  Using x, y and pageNumber coordinates are too much work to keep in sync with document changes; it makes for very fragile code.  We also had to set both anchorCaseSensitive and anchorMatchWholeWord to 'true'.

Comment: Greg, I'm not clear how we can help. What is the question at this point? do you still needs assistance?

Comment: I don't need help anymore, I got it working as desired.

Comment: can you explain what was the issue as to help others who may have a similar problem? you can do that in a answer or I can post an answer.

Comment: was this about anchor strings?

Comment: THere were 2 problems. (1) Anchor strings cause docusign to ignore a tab's documentId and (2) mixing PDF and HTML documents changed the behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a setting at an account level for your DS Account for anchor String population scope, by default it is Envelope scope. So if same anchor string is present on both the documents in the envelope then DocuSign will apply tabs for each signer on each document. To fix this, you need to ask DocuSign Support or your DocuSign's Account Manager to change the scope to Document instead of Envelope from DocuSign's backend Internal Admin tool.

Once scope is set to Document then you can add documentId along-with the anchorString for each String, and it will apply tab for that specific signer only.